# Parse and manipulate http headers and add them to access log in Nginx

Tags: nginx, http-headers

I want to configure nginx so that it parses the http headers and add new parsed strings to access logs. Here is the specific scenario I need:

There is X-Forwarded-For header in incoming requests which contains multiple IP (clients' IP + some proxy server IPs).

```
X-Forwarded-For = "1.2.3.4, 5.6.7.8"
```

Here is log_format configuration in my nginx:

```
log_format  main  '{"timestamp":"$time_iso8601",'
                        '"clientIp":"$http_x_forwarded_for",'
                        '"conSerial":"$connection",'
                        '"agent":"$http_user_agent"}';
```

What I want here  is parse X-Forwarded-For header and extract proxy server's IP and add it in log format with a sepearate tag like this :

```
log_format  main  '{"timestamp":"$time_iso8601",'
                            '"clientIp":"$http_x_forwarded_for",'
                            '"proxy": "5.6.7.8",'
                            '"conSerial":"$connection",'
                            '"agent":"$http_user_agent"}';
```

Note that 1.2.3.4 is clients real ip and 5.6.7.8 is proxy server's ip.

Thanks in advance, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why not just log whole header?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `map` directive can construct the variables you need by using a named capture. For example:

```
map $http_x_forwarded_for $proxy_label {
    default               "";
    "~, (?<proxy_ip>.*)$" "proxy";
}

log_format  main  '{"timestamp":"$time_iso8601",'
    '"clientIp":"$http_x_forwarded_for",'
    '"$proxy_label":"$proxy_ip",'
    '"conSerial":"$connection",'
    '"agent":"$http_user_agent"}';
```

You could do something clever with `$proxy_label` when there is no match, or not.

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

EDIT: To match the last IP address on the line, you could capture only `.` and the digits like this...

```
"~(?<proxy_ip>[0-9.]+)$" "proxy";
```

See this useful [resource for regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refquick.html).

Comment: Hi @Richard, I need some special form of above regular expression; in case of multiple ip addresses in X-Forwarded-For header, the above regex return all list except first ip address. How can I just retrieve last ip in X-Forwareded-For header? (e.g. X-Forwarded-For = 1.1.1.1, 2.2.2.2, 3.3.3.3 and I need just "3.3.3.3" to be returned) Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have added an alternative regular expression.